# Write a simple Vim script to compile java code, and found expand() function return weird path name in Vim script

Tags: vim

I try to write a simple Vim script to compile java code in Vim.

```
function! CompileJava()
    let path = expand("%")
    exec ":!javac " . path 
    let className = expand("%:p:r")
    exec ":!java " . className 
endfunction
```

I got error when I run following line

```
exec ":!java " . className
```

className is  '.home.javacode.test' instead of '/home/javacode/test'

Does anyone know why all the slashes in **className** are replaced with dot?

Comment: Mmm, strange... does that happens also when you (with the file opened) use the following, in the command mode? `:echo expand("%:p:r")`

Comment: When my java file is in the current buffer, I run :echo expand("%:p:r") and it return valid path   /home/javacode/test.   (BTW, I'm in Vim 7.4.729 and Mac 10.9.5).  I also try to use shellescape(),  e.g    className = shellescape(expand("%:p:r")),  but it still got the same result.

Comment: Well, then I think Vim is doing what it is supposed to do. Unfortunately I have no knowledge in Java, but reading the manual in my terminal, I find references to calling a program by a class, and the notation is in "dots". So I think the error message is saying that it needed to be dots instead of slashes. Anyway, how do you do this in your terminal? If you run `$ java /home...` I bet it will give the same error.

Comment: Yep, I got the same error in terminal. I think I need to look at the Java compiler command line options. Thanks for your help

Comment: Please post a new question if you want, a Java question about this (not vim) and I'm sure you will get some answers on that :-) best wishes!